# Centering Flash site on browser zoom in

Tags: css, flash, web, zooming

I have a Flash page that is a bit off center on smaller resolution screens. If the site was centered, and the sides were cut off, then all would be well. But the site starts in the top-left corner, so some content is clipped. I know the problem can be solved in JavaScript, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant, possibly CSS-way, to solve the problem.

Thank you

Comment: could you post a link to the site or an example showing exactly what you try to describe?

Answer (score 0):

horizontally centering a div using css - something like this:

```
.content {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

that's it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to center you content:

```
.content {
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```